# linux tree command with -P flag

Tags: tree

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu 18.10 cosmic) tree  command as follows to get tree view with only specific files and their related directories.

```
tree -P alipay*
```

and result is :

```
.
├── advertise
├── analytics
├── captcha
├── credit_card
├── feed
├── module
├── openbay
├── payment
│   ├── alipay_cross.php
│   ├── alipay.php
│   └── others
├── recurring
└── total
```

But result contains all other unrelated directories as well. I expect only "payment" directory, its parent and subdirectories and files like this:

```
.
├── payment
│   ├── alipay_cross.php
│   ├── alipay.php
    └── others
```

Would you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: tested on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS not Ubuntu 18.10 cosmic.

To remove all other unrelated directories you can use the `prune` option:

```
tree --prune -P alipay*
```

This results in:

```
└── payment
    ├── alipay_cross.php
    └── alipay.php

1 directory, 2 files
```

Prune does not appear in tree's manual, which is somewhat frustrating.

I don't know if there is a way to include the ("others") directory in the result.

Comment: Worked great! appreciated indeed.Not so important including ("others"). Thank you for your time.